# How can I reset UVs, but have them orientated in one way?

Tags: uv

I'm working on a lowpoly scene, and I'd like to make sure the UV's align properly. This is what I'm ideally looking for.

[image: a grid with UVs competely flush]

However, when I use an extruded plane instead of *just using a grid object,* I get this.

[image: A grid with incorrect UVs]

Is there any way I can reset the face orientation, so when I use *UV > Reset* it all faces one way?

Answer (score 0):

Go into edit mode. Seeying your axis I would say to go into top-view too.

Hit [U] and choose 'Project from view'.

Then, when considering the mesh as table; select one row and move it on top of the first 'row'.

Do this too with each column.

Mind 'UV / Constrain to Image bounds' in the UV Editor.

---

Another way is to have just one quad. Set up its UV. Then multiply it eithe by duplicating or using an array modifier.

Comment: This should have been a comment, I'd say myself.