# Is there a way to make all UV's align the same direction with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I'm trying to find a way to rotate all UV's on a mesh to face the same direction.

The closest thing I can find to what I'm trying to do is in this post:
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-programming/in-mel-looking-for-a-way-to-rotate-selected-uv-shells-to-always/td-p/9935600

I've read this post: [How can I reset UVs, but have them orientated in one way?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281669/how-can-i-reset-uvs-but-have-them-orientated-in-one-way) that doesn't really give me an answer to what I need but is the same idea.

[image]
*What I get using Reset*

[image]
*What I get using Reset, then manually rotating each face. This is what I want to do with a script*

Right now in Blender, for the kind of UV's I need, I use the Reset UV option on a mesh to make each face of the mesh fill up the UV 0-1 but they come out all rotated at different directions. Instead of having to select each face and rotate it so it is correct, I want to just have a script that UV resets the UV's and aligns them in the same direction. I have looked into accessing the UV's through Python but UV looping is something that I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding.

I'm using Blender 3.5

Comment: Should be possible by traversing the mesh in Python from a face of choice, but what can also work is putting seams on all vertical edges instead of the edges on the top row of quads, and then just unwrapping…